# Microsoft Azure - sql server replication vs availability groups

Tags: sql-server, azure

What are the main differences between sql-server replication and availability groups in an Azure Iaas data solution? (sql server instances on a VM)
Are these the same concept?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[SQL Server Replication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/availability-groups/windows/overview-of-always-on-availability-groups-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15) copies data and replays changes using SQL Commands to replicas.  Sometimes this is called "Logical Replication".  Replication is typically not used for High-Availability or Disaster Recovery, but can be used to create a readable replica of a production database or to copy selected data from a main database into one or more subscribers.

[AlwaysOn Availability Groups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/availability-groups/windows/overview-of-always-on-availability-groups-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15) copies and applies the log records to syncronize databases.  The changes are applied using the same transaction log redo process that's used in backup/restore and database recovery.  Sometimes this is called "Physical Replication", as the database files on every replica are identical.  AlwaysOn Availability Groups can be used for High-Availability, Disaster Recovery, and to create Readable Replicas of a production database.